# How can I add a line plot to a stacked barplot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]I am plotting a stacked barplot for a variable with different categories. However, I would like to add a line plot on top of it for a variable with numerical values. Here´s my code so you can see what I´ve tried (numerical value not included).

1. My numerical value´s name will be "Thrombosis" and the values for it are c(2,7,4,3), but I do not know haw to integrate it to the ggplot part of my code. I tried adding it with "geom_line" but I get an error.

```
tromboprofil <- structure(list(Period = c("1997-2005", "2006-2011", 
                                             "2012-2017", "2018-2023"), 
                             Aspirin=c(1,44,30,12), 
                             VKA=c(3,4,24,20),DOAC=c(NA,NA,1,23),Heparin = c(NA,1,4,NA), None =c(33,7,16,13)), 
                        .Names = c("Period","Aspirin", "VKA", "DOAC", 
                                   "Heparin", "None"), 
                        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L))

tromboprofil$Period <- factor(tromboprofil$Period,ordered = TRUE,
                                 levels = c("1997-2005", "2006-2011", 
                                            "2012-2017", "2018-2023"))


md <- melt(tromboprofil, id=(c("Period")))

ggplot(data = md,
       aes(x = factor(Period,level=c("1997-2005", "2006-2011", 
                                     "2012-2017", "2018-2023")),
           y = value,
           fill = variable))+
  labs(fill="Thromboprophylaxis")+
  geom_col()+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral")+
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(y), group = Period), 
            stat = 'summary', fun = sum, vjust = -1
  )
```

So far, I got this plot

Answer (score 1):

Put the data you want for your line in a data frame:

```
line_data = data.frame(Thrombosis = c(2, 7, 4, 3), Period = unique(md$Period))
```

Then add a `geom_line` layer to your plot, using that data. When you use `geom_line` with a categorical axis, you also need to use a `group` aesthetic which determines which points are connected by lines. In this case, we want all the points connected so we just set `group` to a constant, like 1. Also, since you specified `fill = variable` in the original `ggplot()` call, which does not apply to the `geom_line` layer, we set `inherit.aes = FALSE` so that this setting is not inherited.

```
ggplot(data = md,
       aes(x = factor(Period,level=c("1997-2005", "2006-2011", 
                                     "2012-2017", "2018-2023")),
           y = value,
           fill = variable))+
  labs(fill="Thromboprophylaxis")+
  geom_col()+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral")+
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(y), group = Period), 
            stat = 'summary', fun = sum, vjust = -1
  ) +
  geom_line(data = line_data,
            aes(x = Period, y = Thrombosis), 
            color = "black", group = 1, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Alternately, you could move the `fill = variable` to the `geom_col()` layer and then you wouldn't have to worry about `inherit.aes = FALSE`, and we don't have to re-specify `x = Period`, as that will be inherited. I've also reorganized your code to put the geoms first, then the scales, then the theme and labels. I find it more readable this way.

```
ggplot(data = md,
       aes(x = factor(Period,level=c("1997-2005", "2006-2011", 
                                     "2012-2017", "2018-2023")),
           y = value))+
  geom_col(aes(fill = variable)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(y), group = Period), 
            stat = 'summary', fun = sum, vjust = -1
  ) +
  geom_line(data = line_data,
            aes(y = Thrombosis), 
            color = "black", group = 1) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
  labs(fill="Thromboprophylaxis") +
  theme_minimal()
```